# Wrong behavior of jQuery Script

Tags: jquery, html, css

please have a look at [Demo Galery](http://c-m-d.info/demo/)

There are some bugs I'm not able to fix.

1. In Safari, the text is flickering while `mouseover` other elements
2. in Safari and Chrome, the images are not the correct size (270x128) - only in Firefox is that shown correct
3. in Firefox the fadeout effect is not smooth

CSS code:

```
div li img{
    width: 270px;
    height: 128px;
    -webkit-transform:scale(0.8); /*Webkit: Scale down image to 0.8x original size*/
    -moz-transform:scale(0.8); /*Mozilla scale version*/
    -o-transform:scale(0.8); /*Opera scale version*/
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s; /*Webkit: Animation duration*/
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s; /*Mozilla duration version*/
    -o-transition-duration: 0.5s; /*Opera duration version*/
    opacity: 1; /*initial opacity of images*/
    margin: 0 10px 5px 0; /*margin between images*/
    box-shadow:0px 20px 10px -15px #000;
}

img:hover {
    -webkit-transform:scale(0.85); /*Webkit Scale version*/
    -moz-transform:scale(0.85); /*Mozilla scale version*/
    -o-transform:scale(0.85); /*Opera scale version*/
    box-shadow:0px 0px 30px #000; /*CSS3 shadow: 30px blurred shadow all around image*/
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 30px #000; /*Safari shadow version*/
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 30px #000; /*Mozilla shadow version*/
    opacity: 1;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -190px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 220px;
    z-index: 9999;
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 0;
}

div li {
    float: left;
    padding: 1px;
    width: 270;
    height: 128px;
}

.darken {
    filter: alpha(opacity=1); /* internet explorer */
    -khtml-opacity: 0.1;      /* khtml, old safari */
    -moz-opacity: 0.1;       /* mozilla, netscape */
    opacity: 0.2;           /* fx, safari, opera */
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s; 
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in, ease-out;
}

.grayscale {
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
    filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); 
}
```

This is my jQuery code:

```
$("#all").on("click", { name: "Alle" }, activateCategory);
$("#eating").on("click", { name: "Essen Trinken" }, activateCategory);
$("#it").on("click", { name: "IT Technik" }, activateCategory);
$("#celebrate").on("click", { name: "Einladen Feiern" }, activateCategory);
$("#education").on("click", { name: "Ausbildung Kultur" }, activateCategory);

function activateCategory(event) {
    if (event.data.name != "Alle") {
        $('li').each(function() {
            //alert("Event: " + event.data.name + "\nTag: " + $(this).data('tags'));
            if ($(this).data('tags') != event.data.name) {
                //alert("treffer in Kategorie " + event.data.name);
                $(this).stop(true,true).addClass("darken",100);
                $(this).append('<div class="overlay"></div>');
            }
            else {
                $(this).stop(true,true).removeClass("darken",100);
                $(this).find('div').remove();
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        $('li').each(function() {
            $(this).removeClass("darken",100);
            $(this).find('div').remove();
        });
    }
}
```

Can anybody help me please with these issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well on this tag

```
<li data-tags="Einladen Feiern"><a href="#"><img class="resizableImage" width="270" height="128" src="img/shots/6.jpg" alt="Illustration"><br></a><p class="description"><a href="#">Feiern</a><br>Beschreibung</p></li>
```

your width in css is

```
width: 270;
```

when it should be

```
width: 270px;
```

the full css for that is

```
div li {
   float: left;
   padding: 1px;
   width: 270px;
   height: 128px;
}
```

[image]

also if something isn't smooth, its probably a rendering issue with the browser and not a lot you can do about it.

Comment: thanks very much... that solved my issue #2. do you have any ideas, why safari reacts "strange" on mouseover?

Comment: Sometimes i come across glitches in my work like a product box on hover `opacity` decreases and it moves to the left `1px` then back, it's really irritating, but sometimes it's near on impossible to figure out why

Comment: the opacity is supposed to do it but moving `1px` isn't

Comment: if I understand you correctly: there's no way to figure out why this happens or to fix that?

Comment: depends, i'm just saying sometimes i get little glitches i haven't been able to solve